# unable to install m2e-wtp maven in eclipse juno

Tags: maven-plugin, eclipse-juno

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

```
  Software being installed: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP 1.0.0.20130613-0136 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp 1.0.0.20130613-0136) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [1.4.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp 1.0.1.20130911-1545) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [1.4.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven JPA Configurator 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.wtp 1.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa [1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033]
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying the install needs the `org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime` plugin with a version of at least 1.4.0 (and not above 2.0.0).

I think Eclipse Juno has an earlier release of this plugin so you will need to move to a newer version of Eclipse to use this.